# Modelling SPX implied volatilities dynamics

Tags: stochastic-processes

I'm interested in constructing a model for the daily implied volatilities of the SPX spanning from 2006 to 2024, considering various tenors (1M, 3M, 6M, 9M, 1Y) and moneyness levels (80, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 120). Ideally, I aim to develop a multivariate process that captures the correlation among all implied volatilities, while also accommodating jumps dependent on time-to-event variables such as macroeconomic releases, speeches, earnings calendars, and dividend calendars. These time-to-event variables will be calculated cyclically. Any suggestions on where to begin in identifying a process that can be calibrated and enables simulation for computing future distributions and risk metrics?

Thank you in advance for your insights!

Comment: Thank you for a very good comment. I really think as you suggest that the history of the event calender could provide interesting input that is not to my understanding available in standard models. Otherwise I am as curious as you are, see my own question: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/78490/index-option-pricing-and-correlation-between-implied-volatlity-vix-and-unde

Answer (score 2):

One good review paper on the issue is this one: [Implied Volatility Surface Construction](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1191887/FULLTEXT01.pdf).

In particular section 8 goes in very detail about 4 different modelling approaches:

1. [Stochastic volatility inspired (SVI)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1779463)
2. [Rough fractional stochastic volatility (RFSV)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.3394)
3. [Stochastic Models of Implied Volatility Surfaces](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/1468-0300.00090)
4. [Analyzing volatility risk and risk premium in option contracts: A new theory](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304405X16000052)

Comment: Can you please explain (a bit) where I can find answers in all the links provided? I'm looking for a multivariate mean reverting process which sigma depends on exogenous variables. Is this request matching with the documentation provided?

Answer (score 1):

I would proceed by defining a model for the dynamics of the volatility surface. Otherwise I think this task would be excesivelly complicated and intensive in computing time. I would suggest something like a Heston model for this: a stochastic volatility model can describe better the evolution of the volatility surface dynamics. Moreover, it is simple enough (does not have many parameters) and you can calibrate it easily (as compared to other models).

Once you have the dynamics specified, you can try to fit the parameters of your model on that daily basis (or maybe weekly?) and see how these evolve through a time series analysis.

I don't know if this answers your question.

Comment: The Heston model could be a solution, and I already have fitted it with QuantLib. The point is how to simulate, with Heston, the implied volatilities (tenors x moneyness) for 6 months ahead? Consider the case where I would like to simulate the ATM for all tenors (1m,3m,6m,9m,1y). What could be done is to calculate the forward implied volatilities, but how to simulate them with Heston?

Comment: In chapter 3 of Gatheral's book there is a way to obtain the implied volatilities for the Heston model. You could use that to get the values you want

Comment: I think one important thing here is to incorporate the calender of known future information releases and events. This has to go into the calendar spreads to separate the dynamics of non-scheduled volatility impacts from the scheduled impacts .

Comment: But that information you'll have it already included in the market quotes/volatility smiles you had on any previous date. I don't think there is a need to take care of this independently, as once you fit any past volatility surface to a model, it's already contained there.

Comment: My first thought, assuming we are using Heston model, is to fit a stochastic interest rate model to capture the term structure. This will essentially allow you to find the correlation associated with the maturity dates. That should allow you to calculate the forward implied volatilities.

Comment: I'm having a look into the approach described by Rama Cont in "Simulation of Arbitrage-Free Implied Volatility Surfaces". In few words, it describes the methodology as simulating (as AR(1) or OU process) the factors constructed via multidimensional-PCA (which describe level, steepness, convexity, etc. of the implied volatility surface). Then, reconstructing the future surface with the simulated factors. It would be interesting to see how non-Brownian diffusion could be implemented (considering exogenous variables) and account for correlations between factors (via Cholesky decomposition).

Comment: @Valter This can be easily implemented with QuantLib as ql.HestonBlackVolSurface(...).blackForwardVol(...). But, lets say for ATM-3M, you will get a curve/line which I'm not sure how to turn into a simulation to understand the distribution of blackForwardVol

Comment: That publication by Rama Cont should definitely help, he seems to have work extensively in those kind of topics