# How is option pricing related to the correlation between implied volatlity and the underlying?

Tags: option-pricing, implied-volatility, risk, volatility-smile, expected-return

The correlation between the index returns (e.g SPX) and its changes in option-impled volatility (e.g. VIX), is strong, stable and negative (the implied volatility feedback effect). To me at least, it follows intuitively that index-options with lower strikes should price higher in standard (Black) implied volatility; expecting to see the vola-skew. This goes for indices and index-options but not for the corresponding relationships for individual stocks.

My first question: isn't it settled then that the SPX/VIX correlation is there to make [intertemporal risk/return pricing](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1062976923001035) of the underlying index versus its expected risk closer to buy-and-hold optimality? Or to put it the other way, isn't the [leverage story](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042713003221) ruled out by the weak correlations and skews for returns and implied volatility innovations for *specific* stock return components?

My second question: is there ways to read out, infer, calibrate with, directly model, the VIX/SPX correlation in standard (Heston?) or novel (index-) option pricing models?