# Areas of research in calibration of stochastic volatility models

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-volatility, heston, calibration, pde

I am working on a thesis in deep calibration of the Heston model, and I wanted to include a section on the historical work, before the use of neural networks in this area.
Thus, I was wondering what are the "areas of research" in classical calibration of stochastic volatility models and if you knew of any good papers I could read and maybe cite for each of them.
A research paper by Teichmann et al. (2020) cites 3 areas for local stochastic volatility models:

1. Monte Carlo methods
2. PDE methods based on nonlinear Fokker-Planck equations
3. Inverse problem techniques

Are these also applicable to stochastic volatility models like Heston?

Thanks a lot

Comment: That is a very interesting research area. Unfortunately, I personally do not have much help to offer, but at least it seems to me that Heston is a good way into the subject. Actually I have posted a question on this subject where you could guide me: https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/78490/23886